# let box-shadow overflow over parent elements?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a box shadow to an `img` element and I have its container with `padding:0px` so it is pretty tightly constrained. Consequently, its box-shadow is unable to overflow out and is just kind of crudely cut off.
[image: example of crude cut-off]
Is there any remedy for this?

Comment: Have you tried `overflow:visible`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
div.container { /* ... styles ... */ overflow:visible; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SExPg/

Comment: I had tried this before but didn't apply it to the container of the container lol. wow. dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to just make the shadow smaller OR make the image smaller so you can have more shadow showing.